# Dynamic Style in React With Css module(Not inline style)

Tags: css, reactjs

I am dealing with a react project. I want to change the css of a component. The component does not accept inline css. So I use a global variable like following. I want to change the backgroundSize property of the component. In the following I update the global variable which is zoomLevel, then use the this.forceUpdate for rerendering the component. When I debug, I see that the render method runs, the value of zoomLevel changes but I can not see it in the view. The backgroundSize does not change.

```
    var zoomLevel = 40   //Global variable
         var styles = theme => ({//Outside of the class

                customGrid: {
                    backgroundSize: `${getZoomLevel()}px ${getZoomLevel()}px `,

                },
               ...

            });

    class Flowboard extends React.Component {
    ...

    ...


         componentWillMount() {


                model.addListener({

                    zoomUpdated: ze => {

                        zoomLevel = ze.zoom//changes the global variable
                        this.forceUpdate()
                        console.log(getZoomLevel())

                    },
                })

            }

render(){
return(
 <DiagramWidget 
                            deleteKeys={!this.props.keysLocked ? [46, 8] : []} 
                            allowCanvasZoom={!this.props.keysLocked || this.props.searchMode}
                            inverseZoom={true}                    
                            allowLooseLinks="false" 
                            maxNumberPointsPerLink="0" 
                            className={`srd-demo-canvas ${classes.customGrid}`}//I expect that the style should be changed
                            diagramEngine={this.state.engine} 
                           // baseClass={classes.customGrid}
                        />
     )
  }
}
```

What is wrong in here I do? Is there any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: "The component does not accept inline css."  Sure it does!  Just pass what you want through props and apply it inline in the JSX of DiagramWidget.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I use inline css like style={{backgroundSize:"150px"}} . But it does not work

Comment: Did you apply it as a prop to DiagramWidget?  Because that won't work.  If you add it to a JSX element, it will work.  You many want to share your attempt at applying the inline style since it seems that would solve your problem easily.

Comment: Of course I give as props to the element like following: `<DiagramWidget 
                    deleteKeys={!this.props.keysLocked ? [46, 8] : []} 
                    allowCanvasZoom={!this.props.keysLocked || this.props.searchMode}
                    inverseZoom={true}                    
                    allowLooseLinks="false" 
                    maxNumberPointsPerLink="0" 
                    className={`srd-demo-canvas ${classes.customGrid}`}
                    diagramEngine={this.state.engine} 
                    style={{backgroundSize:"150px 150px"}}
                />`

Comment: Ok, but what do you do with it after that?  That _could_ work if you use the prop correctly in the JSX of the child.  Seems like you are halfway there.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thank you for your help.  I have solved with indirect mthod whic is :`document.getElementsByClassName("srd-demo-canvas")[0].style.backgroundSize="150px 150px"`